# Javascript 3D carousel not working properly in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, carousel

I'm working on a website for a client who wants a 3D carousel.
I found this which works perfectly in Chrome and FF: http://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/kiajB

HTML:

```
<div id=carousel>
<figure id=spinner>
<img src=//demosthenes.info/assets/images/wanaka-tree.jpg alt="">
<img src=//demosthenes.info/assets/images/still-lake.jpg alt="">
<img src=//demosthenes.info/assets/images/pink-milford-sound.jpg alt="">
<img src=//demosthenes.info/assets/images/paradise.jpg alt="">
<img src=//demosthenes.info/assets/images/morekai.jpg alt="">
<img src=//demosthenes.info/assets/images/milky-blue-lagoon.jpg alt="">
<img src=//demosthenes.info/assets/images/lake-tekapo.jpg alt="">
<img src=//demosthenes.info/assets/images/milford-sound.jpg alt="">
</figure>
</div>
<span style=float:left class=ss-icon onclick="galleryspin('-')">&lt;</span>
<span style=float:right class=ss-icon onclick="galleryspin('')">&gt;</span>
```

CSS:

```
div#carousel { 
  perspective: 1200px; 
  background: #100000; 
  padding-top: 10%; 
  font-size:0; 
  margin-bottom: 3rem; 
  overflow: hidden; 
}
figure#spinner { 
  transform-style: preserve-3d; 
  height: 300px; 
  transform-origin: 50% 50% -500px; 
  transition: 1s; 
} 
figure#spinner img { 
  width: 40%; max-width: 425px; 
  position: absolute; left: 30%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% -500px;
  outline:1px solid transparent; 
}
figure#spinner img:nth-child(1) { transform:rotateY(0deg); 
}
figure#spinner img:nth-child(2) { transform: rotateY(-45deg); }
figure#spinner img:nth-child(3) { transform: rotateY(-90deg); }
figure#spinner img:nth-child(4) { transform: rotateY(-135deg); }
figure#spinner img:nth-child(5){ transform: rotateY(-180deg); }
figure#spinner img:nth-child(6){ transform: rotateY(-225deg); }
figure#spinner img:nth-child(7){ transform: rotateY(-270deg); }
figure#spinner img:nth-child(8){ transform: rotateY(-315deg); }
div#carousel ~ span { 
  color: #fff; 
  margin: 5%; 
  display: inline-block; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  font-size: 2rem; 
  transition: 0.6s color; 
  position: relative; 
  margin-top: -6rem; 
  border-bottom: none; 
  line-height: 0; }
div#carousel ~ span:hover { color: #888; cursor: pointer; }
```

JS:

```
var angle = 0;
function galleryspin(sign) { 
spinner = document.querySelector("#spinner");
if (!sign) { angle = angle + 45; } else { angle = angle - 45; }
spinner.setAttribute("style","-webkit-transform: rotateY("+ angle +"deg); -moz-transform: rotateY("+ angle +"deg); transform: rotateY("+ angle +"deg);");
}
```

Unfortunately it is a disaster in IE11.
I've searched the web for help but it seems that everything is managed by the latest versions of IE so I'm a bit confused.
I do not have much experience with javascript and css, for me everything seems ok.
Does someone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason your feature is failing in IE has to do with the `transform-style: preserve-3d;` rule applied to `figure#spinner1`.

IE support for CSS3 3D features has improved, but according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d) IE10 and 11 still do not support that particular feature of the 3D transform API. When I remove the rule from your CSS, I can see that the whole 3d layout fails when that feature is missing.

There may be another way of nesting and formatting your 3d objects that will achieve the same  visual effect without 'preserve-3d', but it will likely be much more complicated than the implementation you have now.

Another option you might consider is using [threejs](https://github.com/mrdoob/threejs) and WebGL to handle your 3d carousel when necessary CSS 3D attributes are not available in the target browser.

Comment: Internet Explorer only presently supports `preserve-3d` in [an *in progress* build](http://remote.modern.ie) available in the [Windows 10 Technical Preview](http://preview.windows.com).